# R - sequence alignment function taking too long to run

Tags: r, performance, alignment, runtime, bioinformatics

So, I am fairly new to R and I have a runtime question. I wrote the following nested while-loop using the "Biostrings" package (biocLite) in order to link protein sequences from two species if they have a >90% alignment score.

Basically, I input two protein genomes, compare each amino acid sequence in SeqData1 to each amino acid sequence from SeqData2, compute an alignment score, and if the score is >90% I concatenate a list of the protein names that match and the sequence of the SeqData2 protein.

The function does work exactly like it should, only problem is that with the number of proteins that it has to scan I am projecting that the runtime for the whole thing is around 1.4 months. T

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to exponentially speed up the runtime of this function?

Thanks!

R code:

```
SeqScore <- function()
{

source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite()
require("Biostrings")
data(BLOSUM100)


SeqData1 <- readDNAStringSet("SeqData1.fasta")
proNum1 = 84390     # number of proteins in Seq1

SeqData2 <- readDNAStringSet("SeqData2.fasta")
proNum2 = 15194     # number of proteins in Seq


#Create empty list to fill with percent scores and matching sequences:
DList=NULL
QueSeqList = NULL
TotList = NULL

#initiating the counters:
i=1
j=1
c=0

#Perform alignment and generate percent identity scores:
while(i<=proNum1)
  {
  while(j<=proNum2)
    {
  SeqAlign <- pairwiseAlignment(SeqData1[i], SeqData2[j], substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5)
  PercAlign <- pid(SeqAlign)
  if(PercAlign>=90)
  {
    DList = c(DList, names(SeqData1[i]), names(SeqData2[j]))
    QueSeqList = c(QueSeqList, toString(SeqData2[j]))
    c=c+1
  }
  else{c=c+1; print(c)}
  j=j+1
  }
  i=i+1
  j=1 #to reset the inner while loop
  }
unlist<-t(sapply(DList, unlist));
outputMatrix<-cbind(DList,QueSeqList)
outputMatrix<-as.matrix(outputMatrix, ncol=3)
write.csv(outputMatrix, "outputMatrix.csv")
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but when I run your code I get the following error in `readDNAStringSet(...)`: `Error in .Call2("new_input_ExternalFilePtr", fp, PACKAGE = "Biostrings") : cannot open file 'SeqData1.fasta'` (same for SeqData2.fsta).

Comment: The "SeqData1.fasta" is just an arbitrary name I used for example purposes. I plan on using this code for various genomes.

Comment: To get help, you really need to provide a sample dataset (or datasets, in this case). Otherwise what to benchmark against?

Comment: My question is does anyone know of a way to make a code such as this run faster. The code itself works, I assure you. There are literally millions of protein databases on NCBI's GEO if you would like to test one.

Comment: If you provide sample .fasta files (maybe just 5 sequences each?) it makes it much easier for interested parties to troubleshoot your code. While I find your question interesting, I just don't have the motivation to go to NCBI and fetch sample data. Even better if I can just paste the whole code chunk into a fresh r session and run it without further ado.

Comment: Growing your objects incrementally the way you are with `c` appears to be the most significant bottleneck. See *[The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)*, Circle 2: Growing Objects.

Comment: Thanks Blue Magister!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the help page, I think that `pairwiseAlignment` works when it's first argument is a `DNAStringSet` of any length, so the outer loop can be replaced by

```
SeqAlign <- pairwiseAlignment(SeqData1, SeqData2[j],
    substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5)
```

I wouldn't use a `while` loop, but instead aim for an `lapply`, along the lines of

```
results <- lapply(SeqData2, function(elt_j) {
        SeqAlign <- pairwiseAlignment(SeqData1, elt_j,
            substitutionMatrix=BLOSUM100, gapOpening=0, gapExtension=-5)
        pid(SeqAlign)
})
data.frame(toString(SeqData1), rep(toString(SeqData2), each=length(SeqData1)),
    unlist(pid, use.names=FALSE))
```

This saves you from the second circle of the R inferno, and also suggests a simple strategy to parallelize this on non-Windows if the calculations are still slow:

```
library(parallel)
options(mc.cores=detectCores())
results <- mclapply(seq_along(... ## as before
```

It's better to ask the data about it's length than to type it in separately `proNum1 = length(SeqData1)`. Also I hope you're not using `biocLite()` each time you run the script; just once to install the package into any given R installation.

You'll get a more authoritative answer on the [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org/) [mailing list](http://bioconductor.org/help/mailing-list/mailform/) -- no subscription required.

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer. This site is full of really knowledgable people so I am very happy when one or two actually answers a question. Thanks again.